# Can't fade out submenu, with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout, submenu

This is my first question! Certanly you will help me on this.

I´m working on this horizontal menu:

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1.1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1.1.1</a></li>
          </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 1.3</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 2.1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SUBMENU 2.1.1</a></li>
          </ul></li>
      </ul></li>          
    <li><a href="#">MENU 3</a></li>         
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  body 
  {

    font-family: "calibri";
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  #menu
  {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #222;
  }

  #menu ul 
  { 
    line-height: 30px; 
  }

  #menu ul li 
  {
    list-style: none; 
    float: left; 
    position: relative; 
  }

  #menu ul li a 
  { 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 30px; 
    color: white; 
    background-color: black; 
    display: block;
  }

  #menu ul a:hover 
  { 
    background-color: grey; 
  } 

  #menu li ul 
  { 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  #menu li ul li a 
  {
    height: 20px;
    font-size: small; 
  }

  #menu li:hover > ul 
  { 
    display: block;
  }

  #menu li ul li a 
  {
    width: 150px;
  }

  #menu li ul li 
  { 
    padding-top: 1px;
  }

  #menu li ul li ul 
  {
    left: 100%; 
    top: 0;
  }

  #menu li:hover > a 
  {
    background-color: grey;
  }
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {

  $('li > ul').animate({'opacity': 0});

  $('li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('ul:first').stop().animate({'opacity': 1});
  },function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').stop().animate({'opacity': 0});
  });

});
```

As you can see, the fade in effect (with opacity) is working when the option is hovered, but how can I make it fade out? I'm working with IE9.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution ...

At the CSS, I have comment this:

```
/*#menu li:hover > ul { display: block;}*/
```

I have also replace the jQuery with this:

```
$('#menu ul li').hover(function () { $(this).find('ul:first').stop().fadeToggle('fast');});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLyFM/) with the provided code. As you can see, it works just fine, and that is because jsFiddle is set to run Javascript onLoad.

So what you need to do is make sure your function is run after the DOM is loaded, by wrapping it in a code block like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your JS function here

});
```

Comment: It doesnt work ... you can see the fadein effect working, but not the fadeout effect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to fade in the option when your mouse pointer is hovering on it and fade it out when you move the mouse pointer away from the same option. Specify that clearly in your question. But since you are new to SO, you are spared from getting downvoted :P

Making this assumption, you need to write code separately for mousever and mouseout events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('li').mouseover(function(e){
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });

    $('li').mouseout(function(e){
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
    });

});
```

Try reading about mouseover and mouseout events from jquery home page.